# Magento 1.9.1.0 - Invalid callback: Model for core/email_queue::send does not exist

Tags: magento, cron

Not sure what's happened, but a clients site for some reason stopped sending all mail, contact form and all transactional emails.

I have AOE Scheduler which is working, but 2 jobs:

core/email_queue::send
core/email_queue::cleanQueue

don't run. I can try manually or in the schedule, they fail every time. The messages field returns this:

Error while running "core_email_queue_send_all"
    "core_email_queue_send_all" messages:

```
---EXCEPTION---
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid callback: Model for core/email_queue::send does not exist' in /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_Data.php(298): Mage::throwException('Invalid callbac...')
#1 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Job.php(143): Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_Data->getCallBack('core/email_queu...')
#2 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule.php(192): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Job->getCallback()
#3 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/controllers/Adminhtml/JobController.php(92): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(false)
#4 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14098): Aoe_Scheduler_Adminhtml_JobController->runNowAction()
#5 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18482): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('runNow')
#6 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18016): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20808): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

I've searched around but can't see any similar issues or solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've provided, you're using Magento 1.9.1.0 and the AOE Scheduler module.

Magento's `core/email_queue` model [does have a `send` method](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php#L186), and so the AOE scheduler (which is basically just a wrapper over the standard Magento cron) should work fine.

I notice in your stack trace that there's a bunch of `includes` file paths - this means you're using the compiler.

My suggestion would be to either disable the compiler completely, or to disable it and re-enable it again so it regenerates its file cache. It's possible you're missing some files in it.

You don't need to compiler, and while I've personally never used it before, I can say that I have seen lots of questions in the StackExchange sites that are caused by it - at least for now, disable it.

Comment: Hi Robbie, I've disabled the compiler, cleared cache, but still getting the error:

Invalid callback: Model for core/email_queue::send does not exist

Does this mean the core model in Magento is missing?

Comment: Yes, it may do. Have you been playing around with the core? Check that `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php` exists

Comment: Yeah, it's definately there and never touched any core code ever.

Could it be that the cron isn't set up, so it's failing, rather than there being a missing file?

Comment: Phil- no, it wouldn't be the cron. It's a very strange error, essentially saying it can't load the core/email_queue model and call send on it. It'll also be difficult to reproduce, so unsure how to proceed with helping you from here